# Is there a way that I could see if the message is a reply?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjYAZ.png (sorry I cannot post images yet)
Is there a way that I could see if the message is a reply?

In this case, it would get the two emojis. All I would need to know is the message body, the two emojis, and the message it is replying to, "day 72 of smug disliking encrypt".

I can normally just do:

```
    channel = ctx.channel
    messages = await channel.history(limit=200).flatten()
```

However this gets all messages instead of just the reply's. So maybe I would be able to get the replies another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Message.reference`

```py
# loop over messages
if message.reference: # if is not None its a reply
    ...
```